# Reset all values to default using one liner python sqlalchemy code

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model class Employee

```py
from sqlalchemy import (Column, String, Boolean)
    
class Employee():
    __tablename__ = "employee"
    first_name = Column(Text)
    last_name = Column(Text)
    code = Column(Text)
    uuid = Column(String)
    active = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

If I need to reset the values of all columns using python-sqlalchemy code, there is one way like mentioned below.

```py
from employee.model.Employee import Employee


def reset_employee(some_id):    
   employee = Employee.query.filter_by(id=some_id).first()
   employee.first_name = None
   employee.last_name = None
   employee.code = None
   employee.uuid = None
   employee.active = False
   employee.update()
```

Is there any other way to reset all the columns to their default value using 1 line of Python code?

Comment: What would be the reason to do it in one line?